# THC situations and the projection formula

Tags: ct.category-theory

I'm trying to find the real nature of the so-called "projection arrow" for $f^* \dashv f_* $:
$$
f_*(A\otimes f^*B)\leftarrow f_*A\otimes B
$$
which can be found in any monoidal category $(\mathbf V,\otimes)$, and sometimes is an isomorphism (for example, when you look at categories of sheaves and there are suitable hypoteses of flatness over $A,B$).

My problem is that the machinery of "THC-situations" proposed in Gray's paper "Closed categories, lax limits and homotopy limits" seems to apply... *backwards*, and I'm not able to reverse it.

Let me recall a couple of things:

1. A *THC situation* consists of three categories $A_1,A_2,A_3$ and functors $T\colon A_1\times A_2\to A_3$, $H\colon A_2^o\times A_3\to A_1$, $C\colon A_1^o\times A_3\to A_2$ such that
   $$
   A_3(T(a_1,a_2),a_3)\cong A_1(a_1,H(a_2,a_3))\cong A_2(a_2, C(a_1,a_3))
   $$
   $T,H,C$ have respectively to be regarded as generalized tensor, hom and cotensor operations (a paradigmatic example of a THC situation is that of a monoidal closed category, where $T=-\otimes-, HC=[-,-]$). One can denote a THC situation as $\mathfrak t = \lbrace A_1,A_2,A_3,\begin{pmatrix}T\\ H\\ C\end{pmatrix} \rbrace$.
2. One is now interested in linking two THC situations $\mathfrak t, \mathfrak t'$ via adjoint pairs. In what follows $\check G_i \dashv G_i\dashv \hat G_i$ is a string of adjoint functors where $G_i\colon A_i\to A_i'$, for $i=1,2,3$. Now it's easy to prove, for example, that
   $$
   G_3T(\check G_1-,\check G_2-),\;\; G_1H(\check G_2-,\hat G_3-),\;\ G_2C(\check G_1-,\hat G_3-)
   $$
   is a THC situation.
3. It's also easy to prove that $G_1H(a_2,a_3)\cong H'(G_2a_2,G_3 a_3)$ if and only if $T(\check G_1 a_1',a_2)\cong \check G_3T'(a_1',G_2a_2)$, by simple adjoint calculus and the Yoneda Lemma: on the one hand
   $[a_1', G_1H(a_2,a_3)]  \cong [\check G_1 a_1', H(a_2,a_3)] \cong [T(\check G_1a_1', a_2), a_3]$, and on the other hand $[a_1',H'(G_2a_2, G_3a_3)] \cong [T'(a_1',G_2a_2),G_3a_3] \cong [\check G_3T'(a_1',G_2a_2),a_3]$.

This should have now the following pleasant corollary: if I am given two monoidal closed categories $(\mathbf V,\otimes, [-,=])$, $(\mathbf V',\otimes', [-,=]')$ and a couple of adjoint functors $F\colon \mathbf V\dashv \mathbf V'\colon G$, then $G[V,W]\cong [GV,GW]'$ iff $FV'\otimes W\cong F(V'\otimes' GW)$, which is exactly what I need... backwards, because what I need is that the *right* adjoint behaves like this:
$$
 GV'\otimes W\cong G(V'\otimes' FW)
$$
in order to justify the projection formula. Is there a similar TH(C) situation where I can get what I want?

Comment: Asking about THC situations when one's called tetrapharmakon.. really! ;)

Comment: I strive for coherence. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some references that you may find helpful.

1. The most common modern term for "THC-situation" is a [two-variable adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-variable+adjunction).  They can indeed be composed with ordinary adjunctions as you suggest.  More generally they are the binary morphisms in a [multicategory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4520), and indeed a [polycategory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06082),  whose unary morphisms are ordinary adjunctions.
2. The equivalence between a right adjoint being closed monoidal and a "Hopf/Frobenius" condition relating it to its left adjoint is also standard.  This is sometimes called "Frobenius reciprocity" and other times a [Hopf adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+adjunction).
3. The "projection formula" map is indeed "backwards" from the Hopf adjunction map.  The only abstract study I know of that mentions it is [Fausk-Hu-May](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/11/4/11-04abs.html).  Their equation (3.6) gives a general way to define such a morphism for any lax monoidal right adjoint, but they don't mention any "mate" property for it analogous to the Hopf-adjunction/closed-functor duality, and in general it seems such formulas are usually only isomorphisms for a restricted class of "dualizable" objects.